# It is possible to trick pip to use anaconda when possible?

Tags: pip, anaconda, conda

As we are considering switching to anaconda or testing our software with both I would like to know if there is a way to start using anaconda without having to introduce the huge complexity of using a new package manager.

I am wondering if I could make it work like this: when you do pip install ... to use conda to install it and if the package is not in conda to try to use pip instead.

Can this be implemented silently, or at least easily?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the short answer is no. There's been some discussion on the conda issue tracker of having some sort of "all-in-one" command to use conda when possible and otherwise fall-back to pip, but no solution has been created yet: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/931